# How to query by a single value in a list property using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm trying to model a tree structure using a pojo that looks something like:

```
public class Tag {
    String name;
    List<String> ancestors;
}
```

I have a Spring Data repository for this Tag class up and running, which already has a method to findByName defined on it.

I want to be able to query the repository for all Tags which have a named ancestor, i.e the ancestor is a single value in the ancestors list.

Do any of the basic Spring Data query method keywords do this? I wasn't seeing how to do this from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out nothing special is required to achieve this. I added a method onto the repository interface, called getAncestors() which takes a String parameter.

Calling this gives all Tags which have the named Tag in their Ancestor list.

The only thing that's a bit rubbish is the naming that you have to use. A method signature called getAncestors which takes a String and returns a list of items whose anscestors property contains that String isn't ideal.

Comment: Nice find! Is there documentation for this anywhere?